# Passing Services to MainViewModel - SHOULD I use a dependency injection container?

Tags: mvvm, dependency-injection, service, viewmodel, inject

I have this code:

```
public partial class App : Application
    {
        protected override void OnStartup(StartupEventArgs e)
        {
            base.OnStartup(e);        

            var mainVM = new MainViewModel
            (
                new Service1(),
                ...
                new Service10(),
            );

            var window = new MainWindow();
            window.DataContext = mainVM;
            window.Show();

        }
    }
```

I pass all my Services instances to the MainViewModel. Within the MainViewModel I spread those services to other ViewModels via constructor parameter passing.

Should I use any DI framework for the services in the App class?

If yes whats the benefit of resolving the services instead of just creating the instance manually... ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can register all of those types in the container, and have the `OnStartup` method make a single `Resolve` call.

First, have `MainWindow` accept its view model in its constructor:

```
public MainWindow(MainViewModel viewModel)
{
    DataContext = viewModel;
}
```

Then, register `MainWindow` and `MainViewModel` in the container right alongside the services. If `MainViewModel` requires other view models, put those in its constructor and register them as well.

Finally, resolve `MainWindow`, which performs all of the instantiation work:

```
var window = container.Resolve<MainWindow>();

window.Show();
```

The key point here is that a view model is no different from any other class you would register in a container.

Advantages to this approach (from comments):

1) The container makes all the constructor calls for you - you simply have to describe each piece of the graph, and it goes through the tedium of assembling it.

2) `MainViewModel` is freed from having to know how to construct its child view models, which lets it focus on its core responsibilities instead of having to know every single depedency of its children.

Comment: Register the MainWindow and MainViewModel? But how can I register with a DI tool if there implement no Interface?

Comment: *there = they ( see comment above). Another thing is and thats my question actually... WHAT is the benefit (please no general bla bla you are lousely coupled etc...) in concrete terms for my scenario using a DI tool ? I see no advantage.

Comment: Registering under an interface is optional. You can also register components as concrete types, which works perfectly for view models. This is why MainWindow accepts MainViewModel in its constructor.

Comment: There are plenty of questions which address the benefits of DI in general, so I won't rehash them here - you can do a search and read through the ample material. In this specific case, there are a couple of obvious advantages: 1) The container makes all the constructor calls for you - you simply have to describe each piece of the graph, and it goes through the tedium of assembling it. 2) MainViewModel is freed from having to know how to construct its child view models, which lets it focus on its core responsibilities instead of having to know every single depedency of its children.

Comment: @Bryan Your FIRST comment: It seems there is a misunderstanding with the term "Registering". Do you mean instantiate the MainWindow and MainViewModel? Just this I did in my sample. If not then you mean with Registering this:var builder = new ContainerBuilder(); builder.Register<IMainViewModel, MainViewModel>(); _container = builder.Build(); ARE you sure I can register without an interface?

Comment: @Bryan Your SECOND comment: Thank you for not rehashing them, this I wanted to avoid in any case as described above. Sure I can read for myself. To 1) Wether I make ONE single ctor call or the DI tool does it is it that BIG difference, just type a ONE-liner ? This is no advantage for me. To 2) Within my Ctor of the MainViewModel I create my other e.g. 8 ViewModels which are bound to the content in the ContentControl. Where else if not in the ctor of the MainViewModel should I create those ViewModel instances? Create them in the app.xaml.cs and pass them to the Ctor of the MainViewModel?

Comment: Yes, you can register without an interface: builder.Register<MainViewModel>(); I am 100% sure because this is the pattern I use for view models and DI. The container just needs to know *a* type - it doesn't matter if it is the concrete type or something more abstract. It just has to match the type in the MainWindow constructor, like the example in my answer.

Comment: You would register *all* of your view models in the container, just like you did MainViewModel. Thus, when you ask for MainWindow, and that requires MainViewModel, which in turn requires SomeViewModel and OtherViewModel, which each in turn requires 3 more view models, all with their own dependencies, the container can create all of them for you. You shouldn't have to call a single constructor yourself, which frees your code and time up to do more important things.

Comment: Ok that sounds retraceable. BUT what if my 8 ViewModels formerly created in the Ctor of MainViewModel do all execute a database query? With your approach and the DI tool every ViewModel would be created at the beginning of my application and I have 8 database queries being executed at once. That would slow my applications startup time. I do not like that.

Comment: ok I just see I already use your approach concerning the Services injecting via http://mefedmvvm.codeplex.com/ which injects interface types in the Ctor of my MainViewModel automatically via [ImportingConstructor] Attribute over the Ctor. But my ViewModels I can not inject due to my logic in the application because of the loading of much data. What if the user is only navigating to ONE of my ViewModels but loading data for all 8 ViewMOdels? Not good. I will mark your answer as solution as I think there is no better solution in my case.

Comment: It would be be nice Bryan if you could still post your 1) and 2) comment into the solution so people see why I marked it as such one.

Comment: @msfanboy: Since the operations in the various view models are expensive, it makes sense to defer the work until the last possible moment. This might mean loading the data on-demand in response to an event, rather than up-front in the constructor. You can also inject a factory instead, and create the view model on-demand.